# Hoeffding's Inequality Assumptions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I'm looking for the assumptions of the Hoeffding's inequality to check it is applicable to my problem. So far the only assumptions I can find are the variables $Z_i$ are IID and bounded. However, Im wondering if there is some assumption I am missing that assumes the underlying distribution is Gaussian or Sub-Gaussian.

Am I missing any assumptions or is Gaussian or sub-Gaussian implied?

Comment: The general version of Hoeffding's inequality assumes the variables are sub-Gaussian. Since bounded RVs are sub-Gaussian your assumptions are enough. Note that you can also replace the assumption that $Z_i$ is bounded with the assumption that $Z_i$ is sub-Gaussian (as this is 'wider')

Comment: Would it be possible to use the Hoeffding's inequality on the distribution Y~log(Z), if Z is approximately normal? Since Y would be bounded and samples would be IID.

Comment: If Y is bounded and IID then I would say that it is possible, yes.